# Well known Symbols do not work with functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reflection, ecmascript-6, symbols

Consider the following two snippets:

```
obj = {}; // can be [], Number(), eg. but not Function()
obj[Symbol.hasInstance] = () => console.log('89');
({}) instanceof obj;
```

and

```
obj = function() {}; // new Function() too
obj[Symbol.hasInstance] = () => console.log('89');
({}) instanceof obj;
```

Both should log '89' but only in the first snippet '89' is logged.

In Chrome 52, first logs 89, second logs nothing.

In node v6.3.1 first results in `TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>`, while second logs nothing.

Is this a bug? What is the intended behaviour? On MDN there is nothing explaining this.

Comment: The spec says *"This property is non-writable and non-configurable to prevent tampering that could be used to globally expose the target function of a bound function."* But it also says *"A constructor function can control which objects are recognized as its instances by `instanceof` by exposing a different @@hasInstance method on the function."* http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function.prototype-@@hasinstance . According to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-instanceofoperator , the first one should not throw an error in Node. Seems like Chrome is correct.

Comment: But, `@@hasInstance` is in the prototype chain, I am not actually altering it, just creating an another property `@@hasInstance` on `obj`. And the same goes for `new Function()` and `function() {}` too, why are their behaviour different?

Comment: If a property is not writable, you cannot assign to it higher up in the chain. Example: `var a = Object.create(null, {test: {value: 42}}); var b = Object.create(a);`. `b.test = 21;` silently fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Symbol.hasInstance]` property of function is not writable and not configurable:

[image]

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function.prototype-@@hasinstance) says:

> This property is non-writable and non-configurable to prevent tampering that could be used to globally expose the target function of a [bound function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects).

For that reason, the assignment

```
obj[Symbol.hasInstance] = () => console.log('89');
```

silently fails. It doesn't matter that the property is defined on the *prototype*, if it's not writable it cannot be overwritten by "descendants" either.

So the Chrome behavior is correct.

---

As for Node, it seems it doesn't implement the new behavior of `instanceof` yet, i.e. it doesn't use `[Symbol.hasInstance]` if it exists. In that case the right operand has to be a function, which is not the case in the first example.